# Possible to create a "shorthand" method?

Tags: java

(Just a heads up, if some of my methodology isn't 100% correct, I'm a student still learning so please excuse me.)

In lots of my projects for school, I'm having to use `System.out.print("text")` a lot. Is there a way I can create a separate method so I can do something like `sop("text")` and have the same effect?

Comment: Sure. Create a function.

Comment: But what will you get by doing that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]. Could you give us the code that you have, what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: Writing a new method is just an extra work. Are you going to write separate methods to print integers, doubles etc. All the methods given in answers will fail if you pass any other datatype. All these exceptions are already handled  by Java `System` and `PrintStream` classes. Do not waste your time in reinventing a wheel.

Comment: If you are planning to become a professional developer of software after you finish school, Lew Bloch’s answer is the only one you should be heeding.  Saving 1½ seconds of typing is not worth leaving behind cryptic shorthand that other developers on your team need triple the usual amount of time to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just make a method like this:

```
public static void printText(String yourText) {
    System.out.println(yourText);
}
```

Then you can use it by calling on the name of the method and giving it your text that you want to print as the String parameter like so:

```
printText("This will print.");
```

Comment: Please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: My bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner approach seems to be to [statically import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) the method:

`import static System.out.println;`

and then use it as another method:

`println("TEXT");`

Comment: You can't statically import `System.out.println`, because it's not a static method.

Comment: Absolutely true

Comment: 1) package name has to be provided for static imports of objects even in `java.lang` package: `import static java.lang.System.*;` or `import static java.lang.System.out;` 2) thus, replacing `System.out.println` with `out.println` does not seem to be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

The worst thing you can do in this situation is replace a well-known and -understood call that has a readable name with some custom meaninglessly named function that does nothing useful but does confuse maintainers. What problem are you solving? Rescuing sprained fingers from invoking autocomplete or copy-paste? Don't sacrifice readability for laziness.

Comment: Method. I believe it is pronounced method in java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way for doing so. You can basically create a new method that contains the call `System.out.println("...")`.

```
public void log(final String text){
  System.out.println(text);
}
```

But I suggest to do not so: you are encapsulating a method call (System.out.println) in a new method call (to log) without having any added value.

Answer (score -1):

Sure thing.  Just make a method.

```
public static void sOP(String s)
{
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a really easy way to do so actually. I'll show you my code for that:

```
public class ExampleQuickOutput{

    public static void out(String text /*The desired output*/){
        System.out.print(text); //Outputs the text sent
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        out("Hello World!"); //Call to the method
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!